# Strange error when signing in a user after a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I want to sign users in automatically after they create an account. My application is a multi-tenant one where accounts are implemented at subdomain level: *account_name.myapp.com*

I have an `Account` model with `has_many :owners, through: :ownerships`. I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to create an Account and a User model using one form.

I wrote a `before_filter` to handle the signing in, but I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error. I'm not sure how to debug it.

Once the Account and User models are created, I redirect to Accounts#show--where the error happens. I'm passing a `sign_in_token` param. Using a before_filter, I load the user from the token and call a `sign_in` method on it.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :sign_in,  only: :show

  def show
    @account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @owner   = @account.owners.build
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain, sign_in_token: @account.owners.first.sign_in_token)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_in
    if params[:sign_in_token]
      user = User.find_by_sign_in_token(params[:sign_in_token])
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

My `sign_in` methods works normally and I have written tests. It only breaks in this scenario.

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end
```

Error:

```
ArgumentError in AccountsController#show

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Stack

```
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:31:in `sign_in'
app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:34:in `sign_in'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__3150241459892085714__process_action__1436783733275598907__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1668768892136358850__call__837556511977231927__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/mohamad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/mohamad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/mohamad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: add the full stack trace and line that causes this issue.

Comment: Where is the **full stack trace** with **line numbers**?

Comment: more than that... the stack trace with line numbers and function names

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares, I added the wrong trace in the beginning (from another window, while doing a test)--I just updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same name of the function that you are calling

```
def **sign_in**
  if params[:sign_in_token]
    user = User.find_by_sign_in_token(params[:sign_in_token])
    **sign_in user**
  end
end
```

so sign_in user is trying to call the function it is defined in, but with an argument.  probably not what you meant.

As for how to debug, once you posted the stack trace, it became obvious.  `sign_in user` was being passed a parameter when none was expected (1/0)... and the reason was three lines above it. :)

Comment: @Dohh! I feel silly! Thanks. Don't know which answer to choose, so I'll go for the fastest one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a `sign_in` method in your controller that is hiding the `sign_in` method the authentication library you are using has provided, so your `sign_in` doesn't take parameters but the original one does. The fix for this is to rename your method to something else:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :sign_in_user,  only: :show

  def show
    @account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain)
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @owner   = @account.owners.build
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain, sign_in_token: @account.owners.first.sign_in_token)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def sign_in_user
    if params[:sign_in_token]
      user = User.find_by_sign_in_token(params[:sign_in_token])
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

It should work now.